# Z order of core-tooltip

Tags: polymer, core-elements

How do I have to style my `core-tooltip` to have a `z-order` above all other elements. See screenshot:

[image: Tooltip for paper-icon-buttons in a table row]

Currently the `core-tooltip` is behind the next table row.

Comment: Maybe you can try [https://github.com/Polymer/core-tooltip/issues/17] ebidel comment

Comment: @Zesky This does **not** solve the problem above.

Comment: Can you share your html code or maybe create a fiddle for it, so can have a test on your item and tooltip.